# Print const char in cpp

Tags: c++, network-programming

I am trying to print the value of const char* ip variable as below:

```
 int j=0;
 struct server{
 int serverId;
 const char* ip;
 int port;
     };
server serverList[5];  
void x(){
string task2[4];
task2[1]=192.192.192.192;
task2[2]=2021;
    ...
    ...
            if(lineNum<=7){
                    serverList[j].ip=task2[1].c_str();
                    serverList[j].port=atoi(task2[2].c_str());
                    cout<<serverList[0].ip<<endl;
                    j++;
                }
            else{
                cout<<serverList[0].ip<<endl;
                }

    ...
    }
```

The first cout prints the correct value(192.192.192.192) but the second one (just prints a number '2') doesn't.  What could be the reason?

Comment: I dont know how did you managed to compile this

Comment: There is no indication that you ever set the value of ip in the second case. Also the value returned by std::string.c_str() can be invalidated,  so while it works in your sample code, I would be worried about it in general as a source for the value of your char *ip. Better to make your ip member a standard string, so that it actually contains a copy of the string of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the input file, thank you for the response.